# How do I close an image open in a picturebox so I can delete it?

Tags: c#

at the moment my form has a system where i can save the data in the form to a directory in the applications folder then load it again through a listbox i have set up now i need to add a delete button to delete the data out of the folder the problem is if i opened it it returns an error cannot delete  because the file is in use heres the code i use to save the data

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"cards\" + CardName.Text + ".card", false))
            {
                int lev = Level.SelectedIndex;
                int race = Race.SelectedIndex;
                int attribute = CardAttribute.SelectedIndex;
                int cardtype = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
                int monstertype = comboBox2.SelectedIndex;
                int spelltype = comboBox4.SelectedIndex;
                int traptype = comboBox3.SelectedIndex;
                String[] des = CardDescription.Text.Split('\n');
                ImageConverter img_converter = new ImageConverter();
                byte[] bytes = (byte[])img_converter.ConvertTo(IMG, typeof(byte[]));  
                File.WriteAllBytes(@"cards\" + CardName.Text + ".jpg", bytes);
                writer.WriteLine("#ID:" + CardID.Text);
                writer.WriteLine("#lev:" + lev);
                writer.WriteLine("#rac:" + race);
                writer.WriteLine("#att:" + attribute);
                writer.WriteLine("#atk:" + ATK.Text);
                writer.WriteLine("#def:" + DEF.Text);
                writer.WriteLine("#pic:" + CardName.Text + ".jpg");
                writer.WriteLine("#ctp:" + cardtype);
                writer.WriteLine("#mtp:" + monstertype);
                writer.WriteLine("#stp:" + spelltype);
                writer.WriteLine("#ttp:" + traptype);
                writer.WriteLine("#gol:" + checkBox1.Checked);
                writer.WriteLine("#nam:" + CardName.Text);
                foreach (string l in des)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("#des:" + l);
                }
            }
            ListUpdate();
        }
```

to load the data

```
    private void listBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string open = @"cards\" + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + ".card";
        var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(open));
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            if (line.StartsWith("#ID:"))
            {
                CardID.Text = line.Substring(4);
            }
            if (line.StartsWith("#lev:"))
            {
                string lev = line.Substring(5);
                Level.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(lev);
            }
            if (line.StartsWith("#rac:"))
            {
                string rac = line.Substring(5);
                Race.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(rac);
            }
            if (line.StartsWith("#att:"))
            {
                string att = line.Substring(5);
                CardAttribute.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(att);
            }
            if (line.StartsWith("#atk:"))
            {
                ATK.Text = line.Substring(5);
            }
            if (line.StartsWith("#def:"))
            {
                DEF.Text = line.Substring(5);
            }
            if (line.StartsWith("#ctp:"))
            {
                string ctp = line.Substring(5);
                comboBox1.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(ctp);
            }
            if (line.StartsWith("#mtp:"))
            {
                string mtp = line.Substring(5);
                comboBox2.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(mtp);
            }
            if (line.StartsWith("#stp:"))
            {
                string stp = line.Substring(5);
                comboBox4.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(stp);
            }
            if (line.StartsWith("#ttp:"))
            {
                string ttp = line.Substring(5);
                comboBox3.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(ttp);
            }
            if (line.StartsWith("#gol:"))
            {
                string gold = line.Substring(5);
                checkBox1.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(gold);
            }
            if (line.StartsWith("#nam:"))
            {
                CardName.Text = line.Substring(5);
            }
            if (line.StartsWith("#des:"))
            {
                des += line.Substring(5) + Environment.NewLine;
                CardDescription.Text = des;
            }
            if (line.StartsWith("#pic:"))
            {
                if (File.Exists(@"cards\" + line.Substring(5)))
                {
                    IMG = Image.FromFile(@"cards/" + line.Substring(5));
                }
            }
        }  
        des = "";
        GenerateCard();
    }
```

and to delete it

```
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string list = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        if (File.Exists(@"cards\" + list + ".card"))
        {
            File.Delete(@"cards\" + list + ".card");
        }
        if (File.Exists(@"cards\" + list + ".jpg"))
        {
            File.Delete(@"cards\" + list + ".jpg");
        }
        ListUpdate();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so the problem that the `PictureBox` is using the image you want to delete... right?
So, instead of using the picture from local drive, we could load the picture into the `PictureBox`:

```
public Bitmap LoadBitmap(string path)
{
    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        // open file in read only mode
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        // get a binary reader for the file stream
        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
        {
            // copy the content of the file into a memory stream
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length));
            // make a new Bitmap object the owner of the MemoryStream
            return new Bitmap(memoryStream);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error Loading File.", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        return null;
    }
}
```

To use it, just call:

```
picturebox1.Image = LoadBitmap("LOCATION");
```

Now you can delete the picture without locking. But beware, the `PictureBox will not be cleared. You'll have to clear it manually.

I hope it helps. ;)

Comment: it part works i get an error on this part i assume its a function you forgot to post removepic();

Comment: no problem i just removed it now i just need ti figure out how to do the same on the other file and i will be set

Comment: and i didnt want to clear the picturebox what the program does is it nakes an image based on the form values

Comment: juzt place in that pictures path. Call like this :                                    'YOURPICTUREBOX.image = LoadBitmap("IMAGE PATH");                           on DELETE BUTTON CLICK, juzt do 'File.Delete("IMAGE PATH"); :)

Comment: the image part works fine now thanks to you i meant the .card file

Comment: Okay so, you dont want the Image in PictureBox to be Cleared, but still delete the Picture, right ?? The above code works juzt fine. Pls Check it doing a Debug. :)

Comment: as for .card file, *I THINK changing BITMAP type in the LoadImage to FILEINFO will do the trick, with some minor modifications. Try it . :)

Comment: thanks with the other file i just forgot to close the streamreader so it was still being opened my bad thank for the help

Comment: Good solution, except that it would be more reasonable to throw a `FileNotFoundException` rather than to display a `MessageBox` in a utility method.

Comment: mm yea :) thtz a gud idea :)

Answer (score 1):

Nathanael Jones' blog post ["20 Image Resizing Pitfalls"](http://www.nathanaeljones.com/blog/2009/20-image-resizing-pitfalls) describes exactly that problem:

> *"Opening a `Bitmap` or `Image` by filename will cause the file to be locked for the duration of the `Bitmap` instance.*

And this is his suggested solution:

> *"You can avoid the lock by using a `FileStream`, cloning it to a `MemoryStream`, disposing the `FileStream`, then using the `.Tag` property to track and dispose the `MemoryStream` later."*

Answer (score 0):

Use the Load method instead.
eg: pictureBox1.Load(Path to the image);
by using this u will have no problem in deleting the image or the folder before closing the app
hope this helps